# How to add square brackets in JSON object with python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, nested

I just need contexts to be an Array ie., 'contexts' :[{}] instead of 'contexts':{}

Below is my python code which helps in converting python data-frame to required JSON format

This is the sample df for one row

```
name      type  aim      context     
xxx xxx     specs 67646546  United States of America  

data = {'entities':[]}
for key,grp in df.groupby('name'):
    for idx, row in grp.iterrows():
        temp_dict_alpha = {'name':key,'type':row['type'],'data' :{'contexts':{'attributes':{},'context':{'dcountry':row['dcountry']}}}}

        attr_row = row[~row.index.isin(['name','type'])]
        for idx2,row2 in attr_row.iteritems():
            dict_temp = {}
            dict_temp[idx2] = {'values':[]}
            dict_temp[idx2]['values'].append({'value':row2,'source':'internal','locale':'en_Us'})

            temp_dict_alpha['data']['contexts']['attributes'].update(dict_temp)


        data['entities'].append(temp_dict_alpha)


print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4))
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "entities": [{
            "name": "XXX XXX",
            "type": "specs",
            "data": {
                "contexts": [{
                        "attributes": {
                            "aim": {
                                "values": [{
                                        "value": 67646546,
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "context": {
                            "country": "United States of America"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However I am getting below output

```
{
    "entities": [{
            "name": "XXX XXX",
            "type": "specs",
            "data": {
                "contexts": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "aim": {
                            "values": [{
                                    "value": 67646546,
                                    "source": "internal",
                                    "locale": "en_Us"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "context": {
                        "country": "United States of America"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can any one please suggest ways for solving this problem using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
import pandas as pd
import json


df = pd.DataFrame([['xxx xxx','specs','67646546','United States of America']],
                       columns = ['name', 'type', 'aim', 'context' ])

data = {'entities':[]}
for key,grp in df.groupby('name'):
    for idx, row in grp.iterrows():
        temp_dict_alpha = {'name':key,'type':row['type'],'data' :{'contexts':[{'attributes':{},'context':{'country':row['context']}}]}}

        attr_row = row[~row.index.isin(['name','type'])]
        for idx2,row2 in attr_row.iteritems():
            if idx2 != 'aim':
                continue
            dict_temp = {}
            dict_temp[idx2] = {'values':[]}
            dict_temp[idx2]['values'].append({'value':row2,'source':'internal','locale':'en_Us'})

            temp_dict_alpha['data']['contexts'][0]['attributes'].update(dict_temp)


        data['entities'].append(temp_dict_alpha)


print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "name": "xxx xxx",
            "type": "specs",
            "data": {
                "contexts": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "aim": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "67646546",
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "context": {
                            "country": "United States of America"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @chitown. How ever in your above logic,we need nested object 'attributes' to be array instead of object.[{"entities":[{"name":"specs","type":"glass","data":{"attributes":[{"aitm":{"values":[{"value":"70072187","source":"internal","locale":"en_US"}]},"alitm":{"values":[{"value":"ESA65Z45","source":"internal","locale":"en_US"}]},"aaitm":{"values":[{"value":"ESA 65Z45","source":"internal","locale":"en_US"}]},"adsc1":{"values":[{"value":"CUT TIP FG 1808-40","source":"internal","locale":"en_US"}]}}]}}]}]

Comment: Ahhh. Ok I misread that. I see what you mean. I’ll fix this when I get a chance.

Comment: i need your help once again. I am trying to add one object to data in below format. Can you please help me on this. {"entities":[{"name":"xxx xxx","type":"specs","data":{"attributes":{"aimd":{"values":[{"value":"xxxxx","source":"internal","locale":"en_Us"}]}},"contexts":[{"attributes":{"aim":{"values":[{"value":"67646546","source":"internal","locale":"en_Us"}]}},"context":{"country":"United States of America"}}]}}]}

Comment: your data source isn't complete. Where is aimd in your data source to get that value? share the entire row of your data source so I can work out the logic.

Comment: Sorry. Below is the sample datasource. df = pd.DataFrame([['xxx xxx','specs','67646546','TEST 123','United States of America']],
                       columns = ['name', 'type', 'aim', 'aimd','context' ])

Comment: ok. got the solution. Go ahead and open a new question so I can post it there for you, and just post the link to it here so I can get to it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here in the following code

```
 temp_dict_alpha = {'name':key,'type':row['type'],'data' :{'contexts':{'attributes':{},'context':{'dcountry':row['dcountry']}}}}
```

As you can see , you are already creating a `contexts` `dict` and assigning values to it. What you could do is something like this

```
    contextObj = {'attributes':{},'context':{'dcountry':row['dcountry']}}
    contextList = []
    for idx, row in grp.iterrows():
        temp_dict_alpha = {'name':key,'type':row['type'],'data' :{'contexts':{'attributes':{},'context':{'dcountry':row['dcountry']}}}}

        attr_row = row[~row.index.isin(['name','type'])]
        for idx2,row2 in attr_row.iteritems():
            dict_temp = {}
            dict_temp[idx2] = {'values':[]}
            dict_temp[idx2]['values'].append({'value':row2,'source':'internal','locale':'en_Us'})
            contextObj['attributes'].update(dict_temp)
            contextList.append(contextObj)
```

Please Note - This code will have logical errors and might not run ( as it is difficult for me , to understand the logic behind it).  But here is what you need to do .

You need to create a list of objects, which is not what you are doing. You are trying to manipulate an object and when its JSON dumped , you are getting an object back instead of a list. What you need is a list. You create context object for each and every iteration and keep on appending them to the local list `contextList` that we created earlier.

Once when the for loop terminates, you can update your original object by using the `contextList` and you will have a list of objects instead of and `object` which you are having now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Didn't work with your logic. I am getting same old output.